# Typescript | missing property in generic indexable type

Tags: typescript, types, properties, typescript-typings, redux-toolkit

I was was curious how Redux Toolkit works under the hood and tried to replicate a basic implementation. But I ran into an issue regarding the indexable type `AnyAction` and the type `PayloadAction` that has a defined property called `payload`.

The `builder.addCase` function expects a reducer function as the second parameter. This reducer in turn has 2 parameters `state` & `action`. The `action` parameter defaults to `AnyAction`. The moment I manualy set the type of `action` to `PayloadAction<P>` an error pops up regarding the missing property `payload` in type `Action<string>`.

I cannot seem to get my head around it and was hoping someone could help me out and explain to me why this does not work.

[link to TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQWxgQiQB4AVOUVJAEwGc5MkBPOAXjgZimQHMAfHADeAKDiS4MVmGAAuOBTEBfMWNCRYiFGiy4CbQsVLUQtRgSIkkoiVIDaNKJgAKUCGAaKefJPwBdRRZWVXVNaHhkVAwcPFdMVgAbCEw6YxsyV05mNmEaYHomDNNxKTgwRJS0xVcwsWxSHjgAIwBXBCS6NByyqTS6AGFMBmAACntyyRk5AHkoEqRBqGBMGGgfXgEAGjgVujbcKEUyfDMLYutTLnwjK6RBMZ41hVzWXZwTJEV8AEpOYQANwgCDokzg-3E4PKKxgbSgtnanW6UHBajUYiRXTQADoBsNRmMAOSoHhE3ZPGAvD73WpVVLpe5kJBtAC2LTQgn%20HGEfUknxsOMqyQZql%20eLoQxG4xJwB4aHJcEp1OY925vPBAtIYvUQA)

```
export interface Action<T extends any = string> {
    type: T
}

export interface AnyAction extends Action {
    [extraProps: string]: any
}

export interface PayloadAction<P = any> extends Action {
    payload: P
}

const builder = {
    addCase(
        typeOrActionCreator: string, reducer: <A extends Action = AnyAction>(state: any, action: A) => void
    ) {

        return builder
    }
}

builder.addCase('test', (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
    action.payload
}).addCase('tester', (state, action) => {
    action
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are using this, `addCase()` should be generic and the `reducer` argument is not generic, it just uses the type parameter from `addCase()`.

Try this:

```
const builder = {
    addCase<A extends Action = AnyAction>(
        typeOrActionCreator: string,
        reducer: (state: any, action: A) => void
    ) {
        return builder
    }
}
```

You should put the generic where you want to the type to be inferred. In your case when you call `addCase()` you infer the payload type, and from then on the `reducer` function will always use that payload type. It's locked in and you cannot pass a different type as the payload. That's why `reducer` is *not* a generic function.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQWxgQiQB4AVOUVJAEwGc5MkBPOAXjgZimQHMAfHADeAKDiS4MVmGAAuOBTEBfMWNCRYiFGiy4CbQsVLUQtRgSIkkoiVIDaNKJgAKUCGAaKefJPwBdRRZWVXVNaHhkVAwcPFdMVgAbCEw6YxsyV05mNmEaYHomDNNxKTgwRJS0xVcwsWxSHjgAIwBXBCS6NByyqTS6AGFMBmAyfDMLYutTLnwjGaRBAAp7cskZOQB5KBKkQahgTBhoH14BABo19cO6NtwoRWWeY4Vc1gvmRcV8AEpOYQANwgCDo13+fXWcEOMDaUFs7U63Sg1zUajEiK6aAAdANhqNlgByVA8QmfZ4wV6fHAmJC1KqpdKLMhINoAWxaaEE-w4wkhX1p2MqyUZql+uLoQxGwCJJJiZLgFKpApsPL51xpNjF6iAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use createAction and passing the type for payload like this:

```
const incrementByAmount = createAction<number, 'increment'>('increment')
```

Now if you hover over the `action`, you will see the type will be `increment` & payload will be number.

In redux toolkit, they already have a example how you can set the type of payload.
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createreducer

Complete Example From Redux Toolkit Documentation.

```
import { createAction, createReducer } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

interface CounterState {
  value: number
}

const increment = createAction('counter/increment')
const decrement = createAction('counter/decrement')
const incrementByAmount = createAction<number>('counter/incrementByAmount')

const initialState = { value: 0 } as CounterState

const counterReducer = createReducer(initialState, (builder) => {
  builder
    .addCase(increment, (state, action) => {
      state.value++
    })
    .addCase(decrement, (state, action) => {
      state.value--
    })
    .addCase(incrementByAmount, (state, action) => {
      state.value += action.payload
    })
})
```